# docker import data in mongodb successfull but nothing in database

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My database is created but no collection inside :/

This is ly logs with the command -> docker-compose logs :

```
Attaching to dockernode_dbseed_1, dockernode_app_1, dockernode_db_1
dbseed_1 | 2015-12-23T16:21:04.228+0000 connected to: db:27017
dbseed_1 | 2015-12-23T16:21:04.286+0000 imported 2 documents
db_1     | 2015-12-23T16:06:37.127+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=18f02be6b100
db_1     | 2015-12-23T16:06:37.128+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
db_1     | 2015-12-23T16:06:37.128+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git 
db_1     | 2015-12-23T16:06:37.135+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
app_1    | warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
app_1    | warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
app_1    | info:    Forever processing file: /hp_app/hp-climatology-api/index.js
app_1    | warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
app_1    | warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
db_1     | 2015-12-23T16:06:37.152+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0)
```

/dbseed/Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo

COPY climat.json climat.json

RUN adduser --gecos '' --disabled-password mongod \
    && mkdir -p /mongo_app \
    && chown -R mongod /mongo_app

USER mongod

WORKDIR /mongo_app

COPY run_mongo.sh run_mongo.sh

USER root
RUN chown -R mongod:mongod /mongo_app
CMD ["/mongo_app/run_mongo.sh"]
```

/dbseed/run_mongo.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
mongoimport --host db --db hpApiDev --port 27017 --collection coll --type json --file /files/climat.json --jsonArray;
sleep 10;
```

this is /dbseed/climat.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "Joe Smith",
    "email": "jsmith@gmail.com",
    "age": 40,
    "admin": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Jen Ford",
    "email": "jford@gmail.com",
    "age": 45,
    "admin": true
  }
]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mongo
  ports:
   - 27017:27017

dbseed:
  build: ./dbseed
  links:
    - db
  volumes:
    - ./dbseed:/files

app:
  build: .
  links:
   - db:db
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: OK my bad ... so the first problem was in my application , my database for dev , test and prod was : `database: 'mongodb://localhost/prod'` instead of `database: 'mongodb://db/prod'` and my second problem was i looked only with robomongo to check my colllections and of course i didin't know that robomongo doesn't work with mongodb 3.0+ so robomongo can't show collections :/ but the collections were present ...maybe my errors will be able to allow at someone to find more faster it error ;)